# Multiple SELECT statements with different conditions in one query

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-python

I have the following tables:

'Prices'

```
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id         | mediumint(9) | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| product_id | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| price      | text         | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| date       | text         | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| time       | text         | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

'Products'

```
+-----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field           | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id              | mediumint(9) | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| category_id     | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| product_urls    | text         | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| product_title   | text         | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| product_image   | text         | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| product_content | text         | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

The connection here is between `Products.id` and `Prices.products_id`.

I have a script running that grabs the URLs, scrapes prices from particular web pages and then updates the 'Prices' table every hour.

I'd like to display the following, ideally with one database query:

- products.product_title
- products.product_image
- prices.price (current price, i.e. the very last insert for each product id)
- The percentage difference between today's average price and yesterday's average price
- The percentage difference between the current month's average price and the previous month's average price

I can do these things separately, but I cannot bring it together into one query.

Just for clarity, I am wanting to grab all of the products at once within a particular category - with that in mind I have been doing this:

```
...WHERE category_id=%s...GROUP BY product_id...
```

I am writing my SQL directly, specifically using the MySQLdb Python library.

Comment: If you can do these separately you can make it in one query by using subselects for the prices stuff by matching the internal prices.product_id (from the subselect) with the outer products.id.

Comment: It's time to learn about data types. Use DATETIME for datetime, DECIMAL for price, and (probably) VARCHAR and INT for everything else

Comment: @Cosmin Can you give some examples?

Comment: @strawberry what's the benefits there, memory allocation?

Comment: Primarily, it's about optimization.

Comment: @Strawberry, thanks, I'll revise these.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Untested example for the first subselect (make the other subselects on this template) :

```
SELECT p.*,
     (SELECT prices.price
          FROM prices
          WHERE prices.product_id = p.id
          ORDER BY prices.id DESC
          LIMIT 1) as last_price
FROM product p
WHERE p.category_id = 4;
```

Probably not the most efficient way tough...

Comment: Excepted your answer, thanks again! :)

Could you just explain the starting p.* I don't get how that's working?

Comment: @Adders It means "all columns from table p" and it's a bad habit that you should avoid in most cases. List `p.product_title, p.product_image, p.price` explicitly if those are the columns you want.

Comment: @Air yes it is a bad habbit and since the query was anyway incomplete, instead of writing the needed cells, I have just written *, sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 0):

Final snippet as per @Cosmin's suggestions...

```
SELECT p.*,
     (SELECT prices.price
          FROM prices
          WHERE prices.product_id = p.id
          ORDER BY prices.id DESC
          LIMIT 1) as last_price,

     (SELECT ROUND(AVG(prices.price), 2)
          FROM prices
          WHERE prices.product_id = p.id AND date = CURRENT_DATE()
          ORDER BY prices.id DESC
          LIMIT 1) as todays_average_price,

     (SELECT ROUND(AVG(prices.price), 2)
          FROM prices
          WHERE prices.product_id = p.id AND date = SUBDATE(CURRENT_DATE, 1)
          ORDER BY prices.id DESC
          LIMIT 1) as yesterdays_average_price,

     (SELECT ROUND(AVG(prices.price), 2)
          FROM prices
          WHERE prices.product_id=p.id AND MONTH(date)=MONTH(current_date)
          ORDER BY prices.id DESC
          LIMIT 1) as current_months_average_price,

     (SELECT ROUND(AVG(prices.price), 2)
          FROM prices
          WHERE prices.product_id=p.id AND MONTH(date)=MONTH(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
          ORDER BY prices.id DESC
          LIMIT 1) as previous_months_average_price
FROM products p
WHERE p.category_id=%s;
```

Wasn't 100% sure on how to do the calculation of percentage difference within the query but I will just do that with Python to keep the query clean.